# Unable to find the machine epsilon for float in c++ in codeblocks

Tags: c++

I wanted to find out the machine epsilon for float and double types through C++, but I am getting the same answer again and again for each data type of variable `x`   I am using, which is that of long double and of the order of O(1e-20). I am running it on my Windows 10 machine using Codeblocks.

I tried using the same code in Ubuntu and also in DevC++ in Windows itself, I am getting the correct answer. What is it that I am doing wrong in codeblocks. Is there any default setting?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //double x = 5;
    //double one = 1;
    //double fac = 0.5;

    float x=1;
    float one = 1.0;
    float fac = 0.5;

    // cout <<"What is the input of number you are giving"<< endl;
    // cin >> x;

    cout <<"The no. you have given is: "<< x << endl;
    int iter = 1;

    while(one+x != one)
    {
         x = x * fac;
        iter = iter + 1;
    }

    cout<<"The value of machine epsilon for the given data type is "<<x<<endl;
    cout<<"The no.of iterations taken place are: "<<iter<<endl;

}
```

Comment: `machine epsilon for float and double types`, it's not the way it works. between 2 near float or double, the epsilon isn't a constant. The float and double aren't stored as integers.

Comment: What is the exact definition of epsilon you are using and how does your algorithm relate to that? That said, your question is off-topic, please see the posting guidelines.

Comment: Can you give us the full compilation options used by codeblocks ? (like fast-math, O3, etc.).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Definition used is largest no. added to 1 such that 1+x is  equal to 1.

Comment: @Mannish -- A more standard definition is the smallest number `x` such that one+`x` is not equal to one. Either definition is a bit problematic due to promotion and rounding. A better definition is the difference between the first representable number that is larger than one and one itself. This is the definition used by `std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> while(one+x != one)
> ```

The computation of `one+x` might well be an extended precision double. The compiler is quite free to do so. In such an implementation, you will indeed see the same value for `iter` regardless of the type of `one` and `x`.

The following works quite nicely **on my computer**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template <typename T> void machine_epsilon()
{   
    T one = 1.0;
    T eps = 1.0;
    T fac = 0.5;
    int iter = 0;
    T one_plus_eps = one + eps;
    while (one_plus_eps != one)
    {   
        ++iter;
        eps *= fac;
        one_plus_eps = one + eps;
    }   
    --iter;
    eps /= fac;
    std::cout << iter << ' ' 
              << eps << ' ' 
              << std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() << '\n';
}   

int main ()
{   
    machine_epsilon<float>();
    machine_epsilon<double>();
    machine_epsilon<long double>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this code to obtain the machine epsilon for `float` values:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
int main(){
  std::cout << "machine epsilon (float): "
            << std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: While true and more correct, I guess the OP is more interested in finding epsilon manually.

Comment: @black I agree, but I thought it might be helpful to indicate that the STL contains such a function, hoping it could be of use for the OP or others.

Comment: You can add a note about [`std::nextafter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) too.

Comment: @RHertel I do want to find it out myself.